Why is consuming kafka messages slow in Flink?
Messages are being produced to Kafka faster than they are being consumed in Flink.
When I produce 1.3 million messages per second to Kafka, the Flink consumer processes about 1.2 million messages per second. I measured this throughput by aggregating the numRecordsInPerSecond metric shown for each source subtask. Initially, the records-lag-max metric for a given subtask shows a lag of a few hundred thousand records, which steadily increases to over a million records.
To address this, I decided to lower the number of messages produced to Kafka to 100,000 per second. My reasoning was that if Flink can handle 1.2 million messages per second, it should manage 100,000 records per second without any consumer lag. I kept all resource allocations the same. However, I still observed consumer lag in the records-lag-max metric, approximately 10,000 records. I expected this lag to be zero.
Below is the code of the test flink job.
env.setParallelism(25);
env.setMaxParallelism(25);

........

var ssgKafkaSource = SlotSharingGroup.newBuilder("kafka source")
                .setCpuCores(5.3)
                .setTaskHeapMemoryMB(19666)
                .build();

var deserializationSchema = ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific(Message.class, jobProperties.schemaRegistryUrl);

KafkaSource<Message> source = KafkaSource.<Message>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers(jobProperties.bootstrapServers)
        .setGroupId(jobProperties.consumerGroupId)
        .setTopics(jobProperties.inputTopic)
        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets(OffsetResetStrategy.LATEST))
        .setValueOnlyDeserializer(deserializationSchema)
        .build();
         
DataStream<Message> messages = env
                    .fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source")
                    .slotSharingGroup(ssgKafkaSource);
    
var messages = messages.map(m -> 1);

In terms of serialization I followed the guidelines outlined in flink serialization tuning and ensured I was using flinks avro serializer, by including the flink-avro dependency and having my Message type extend SpecificRecordBase.
A Task Manager (TM) is run on a EC2 instance with 32vCores, 256GB and SSDs optimized for fast storage I/O latency. I read through the case study impact on disk on rocks db state backend... and am pretty certain I can rule out the issues faced here.
I've tried modifying the Kafka consumer properties, such as the "fetch.max.bytes" and "max.poll.records" but they seem to have no real effect.
The Kafka topic I'm consuming from has 25 partitions.
Is there something I'm not considering here?

There could be a few things at play that could introduce the latency, but it'd be difficult to know exactly without knowing more about the job itself. What kind of delivery guarantees are using for the records that you are writing? Are you writing the messages that you process to a given sink (or multiple) as the delays in writing those could increase the latency. What about checkpointing? Do you have an aggressive checkpointing interval as that would help with processing time. You can consider using the flame graph (enabled via rest.flamegraph.enabled) to see details about processing times.

What you see above is the full job (source -> map). I deliberately removed all operators and sinks in the pipeline, to replicate the issue with the simplest job possible. I disabled checkpointing, would re-enabling and adding an aggressive checkpointing interval help? In regards to delivery guarantees do mean from the producer to Kafka? As this job is just reading from Kafka and not writing to it. Thank you for tip about the flame graph I'll see what it can tell me

I'd recommend trying out an aggressive checkpointing interval (and reenabling it if disabled). Checkpointing would force Flink to commit the Kafka offsets at more rapid frequency and let it know to continue pulling since thing were progressing. And I had asked the delivery guarantees if sink(s) were involved as having something like exactly once can introduce latency while you wait for acks, etc.

Maybe few (2 or 3) of the 25 partitions are getting A LOT of data while other are not? You have 1-to-1 relationship with partitions and parallelism so few of your consumers are burdened with huge data while others are not? If possible in your case, can you try spreading the data evenly to all partitions?
